# AWS Elastic IPs instead of Public IPs?

Tags: amazon-ec2

Why doesn't AWS allocate elastic IP's to all the servers being spawned? They allocate public IP by default to all the servers, which gets lost after a reboot of EC2 instances.

What's the logic behind not allowing elastic IPs automatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TL;DR Because Elastic IP (EIP) addresses are not needed for all/most use cases.

There is a limited supply of routable IP addresses.  If every server on a public subnet received one, those IP addresses would remain allocated even when the servers were off.  If the server was terminated it would be unclear if the use of that IP was concluded or is still necessary for other use.  Which brings up the real reason for Elastic IP's.

> An Elastic IP address is a static IPv4 address designed for dynamic cloud computing. An Elastic IP address is associated with your AWS account. With an Elastic IP address, you can mask the failure of an instance or software by rapidly remapping the address to another instance in your account. [[1]](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/elastic-ip-addresses-eip.html)

The take away from this is if you're not using EIP's for dynamic cloud computing you're probably using them incorrectly.  This is a good example of a correct use case.

> If you require a persistent public IP address that can be associated to and from instances as you require, use an Elastic IP address instead. For example, if you use dynamic DNS to map an existing DNS name to a new instance's public IP address, it might take up to 24 hours for the IP address to propagate through the Internet. As a result, new instances might not receive traffic while terminated instances continue to receive requests.[[2]](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/using-instance-addressing.html)